# What adapter do I need to connect Mr. Heater F273704 to a LP gas tank that has

Tags: hose, adapter

Not knowing that this is something I have to pay attention to I bought this hose
https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B001CFWF5U/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1
The right side of the hose is fine, the left side connector does not match the gas tank connector (my understanding is that the hose is POL make and the tank is Type 1 female)
[image]

but my propane tank takes this
[image]
[image]

What adapter or combination of adapters do I need to be able to connect my MR Heater heater to my 20 LB propane tank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left-side connector on the upper hose is called POL. The connector on the lower hose is called ACME or type 1.

Have you tried the POL hose yet? I have not yet met a propane tank that accepts the ACME/type 1, but was not also compatible with the POL. Look into the valve on your tank. If it's threaded on the inside then the POL will work. Don't forget: the ACME uses a right-hand thread (rightie-tightie) but the POL uses a left hand thread. In other words POL must be turned in the "loosen" direction to tighten it.

Comment: You are damn right, I have no experience with these things, it worked! Thanks a lot !